# Mocking class instantiated in other class in Magento

Tags: dependency-injection, mocking, phpunit, magento-1.9

I'm trying to learn more on testing but unfortunately I have to do it in Magento 1.9.* :)

Consider the following code (GDPR related)...

```
class Vendor_Module_Helper_Data 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->config = Mage::helper('vendor_module/config');
    }

    public function anonymizeEmail(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer $customer)
    {
        return preg_replace_callback('#{([a-z_]*)}#', function ($matches) use ($customer) {
            return strtolower($customer->getData($matches[1]));
        }, $this->config->getEmailFormat());
    }
}

class Vendor_Module_Helper_Config 
{
    public function getEmailFormat()
    {
        return Mage::getStoreConfig('vendor_module/email/format));
    }
}
```

I'm writing a test that asserts that given a customer the email is formatted in the correct way like this:

```
public function it_anonymizes_customer_email()
{
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                    ->setEntityId(1)
                    ->setFirstname('Customer')
                    ->setLastname('Anonymous');

    $configStub = $this->createMock(Vendor_Module_Helper_Config::class);

    $configStub->method('getEmailFormat')
         ->willReturn('customer.{entity_id}@anonymo.us');

    $email = Mage::helper('vendor_module')->anonymizeEmail($customer);

    $this->assertEquals($email, 'customer.1@anonymo.us');
}
```

Of course this will not work as is, but it should be clear what I try to achieve here...

My question is how to make this work best without using DI, which Magento is lacking.

Is there a way to mock a class that is instantiated (protected) in the constructor of another class? Is this best practice?

Or would this be a valid solution:

```
class Vendor_Module_Helper_Data 
{
    public function __construct($args)
    {
        $this->config = isset($args['config'] ? $args['config'] : Mage::helper('vendor_module/config');
    }
}
```

And then in the test:

```
$email = Mage::helper('vendor_module', ['config' => $configStub])->anonymizeEmail($customer);
```

I would have to change the class from a Helper to a Model, since a helper doesn't accept constructor params (I think).

Some advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case I think it would be better to have:

```
class Vendor_Module_Helper_Data 
{
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return Mage::helper('vendor_module/config');
    }

    public function anonymizeEmail(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer $customer)
    {
        return preg_replace_callback('#{([a-z_]*)}#', function ($matches) use ($customer) {
            return strtolower($customer->getData($matches[1]));
        }, $this->getConfig()->getEmailFormat());
    }
}
```

And in your test:

```
public function it_anonymizes_customer_email()
{
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                    ->setEntityId(1)
                    ->setFirstname('Customer')
                    ->setLastname('Anonymous');

    $configStub = $this->createMock(Vendor_Module_Helper_Config::class);

    $configStub->method('getEmailFormat')
         ->willReturn('customer.{entity_id}@anonymo.us');

    $helper = $this->createMock(Vendor_Module_Helper_Data::class, ['getConfig']);
    $email->expects($this->once())->method("getConfig")->willReturn($configStub);

    $this->assertEquals('customer.1@anonymo.us', $helper-> anonymizeEmail($customer));
}
```

So you are creating a method getConfig, then mocking it to return another mock you created.

On another note, for testing in Magento 1.X I'd recommend using module [EcomDev](https://github.com/EcomDev/EcomDev_PHPUnit) which makes testing a lot faster, and allows you to set up magento specific fixtures. It has not been maintained in a while, but it works pretty well, and it will help you to write the tests quicker.

Comment: That cleared things up, tnx. I guess I could also add a `setConfig()` method and pass the $mock that way. DI can also work with setter methods, right?

Comment: yes absolutely! you might want to check out EcomDev though as well, as it allows methods as $this->replaceByMock() which means that if you're instantiating, say a helper inside your method, as long as it's a magento helper you can then just replace it.

Comment: I looked at EcomDev, but we're using a custom built Magento setup using `magento-composer-installer` and a lot of other Composer packages. Requiring EcomDev gave us a lot of conflicts :/ Their PHPUnit version is 4.* for example. We're playing around with `digitalpianism/testframework` right now, probably a lot simpler than EcomDev, but it suits our needs for now, since we're mostly testing our own business logic.

Comment: fair enough, I'll have a look at the testframework you mentioned, might be useful for us! good luck with your testing!